# SSIS - Size of SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis

my SSISDB is writing a large number of entries, especially in [internal].[event_messages] and [internal].[operation_messages].

I have already set the the number of versions to keep and the log retention period to 5 each. After running the maintenance job, selecting the distinct dates in both those tables shows that there are only 6 dates left (including today), as one would expect. Still, the tables I mentioned above have about 6.5 million entries each and a total database size of 35 GB (again, for a retention period of 5 days).

In this particular package, I am using a lot of loops and I suspect that they are causing this rapid expansion.

Does anyone have an idea of how to reduce the number of operational and event messages written by the individual components? Or do you have an idea of what else might be causing this rate of growth? I have packages running on other machines for over a year with a retention period of 150 days and the size of the SSISDB is just about 1 GB.

Thank You!

Comment: What Logging level is the package set to when you run it? If you don't know how to check, *how* are yo running the package(s)?

Comment: It is set to Basic. Setting it to None isn't really an option. Do you think using a custom logging level may do the trick? Tim Mitchell seems to be saying that [internal].[operations] and [internal].[executions] are logged regardless of the logging level specified (https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2017/03/31/ssis-catalog-logging-tables/)

Comment: Using a custom logging level with only warnings and errors will definitely lower the amount of space used.

Comment: Damn it. It turns out that there is no custom logging level for SQL Server 14 :(